# mysql stored procedure - check if query returns no result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-backup

I am creating a stored procedure, where I'm backing up certain values from my main database into another.

I have a loop that runs over the all tables and for certain tables I have different statements to create the backup tables, but they all look similar to this:

```sql
SET @backupQuery= NULL;
IF (tableName IN ('some_table', 'another_table')) THEN  
    SET @backupQuery= CONCAT(
        'CREATE TABLE backup.', tableName, ' AS',
        ' SELECT * FROM mydb.', tableName
        ' WHERE row = "criteria");
ELSEIF (tableName IN ('table_with_other criteria')) THEN
    SET @backupQuery= CONCAT(
...

IF (@backupQueryIS NOT NULL) THEN
    PREPARE stmt from @backupQuery;
...
```

If the Select statement returns no rows, it still creates an empty table, this is something i don't want to have.

**What will be the best way to avoid the empty tables?**

My idea was to split into two parts: the `SELECT` part and the `'CREATE TABLE backup.' ,tableName, ' AS'` part. Check if the SELECT statement returned any rows. 
But I'm not sure how I can accomplish this.

Another approach would be to delete all empty tables in the end, but I really don't like this as the procedure is doing useless things.

Comment: Get `COUNT(*)` from the table to be backed up with the same `WHERE`, and perform the table creation only if the value returned is not zero.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this, but how can I check this with inside a IF since my query is just a string?

Comment: Wrap whole IF like `IF 0=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM .. WHERE ..) THEN {your current IF .. ELSE .. END IF;} END IF;` - or wrap separate actions, if they needs to check different tables for records amount.